# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^4}{n^4+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

$$n^4+n^4>n^4+1 \rightarrow \frac{1}{n^4+n^4}<\frac{1}{n^4+1}$$

for all $n>1$. Then:

$$\frac{1}{n^4+n^4}<\frac{1}{n^4+1} \rightarrow \frac{n^4}{n^4+n^4}<\frac{n^4}{n^4+1} \rightarrow $$ $$\frac{n^4}{n^4+n^4} = \frac{n^4}{2n^4} = \frac{1}{2} < \frac{n^4}{n^4+1}\rightarrow$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2} <\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^4}{n^4+1}$$

then the series diverges by comparsion, because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}$ diverges.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It would help if you actually asked the question before giving your answer. But yes, $n^4/(n^4+1)$ does not converge to $0$, so the series cannot converge.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is correct,
but your proof is wrong.

Instead of taking
the sum to $\infty$,
you need to take it
to $m$
and show the result
diverges as
$m \to \infty$.

In your case,
modify your proof to
$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{n^4}{n^4+1}
\ge \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{n^4}{n^4+n^4}
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac12
=\frac{m}{2}
\to \infty
$
as
$m \to \infty$.

Comment: Why? Could you please explain why I'm wrong|? Thanks.

Comment: Concise and clear.  +1

Comment: @ Magnatta: The sum to $\infty$ is meaningful only once you have proved that it converges. If your goal is to prove a sum diverges, you *have* to show that the sum with $m$ terms diverges as $m \to \infty$.